# Could not connect to the endpoint url for SQS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I am having trouble connecting to SQS via the aws-cli. I searched through many different solutions on SO yet it still does not work.

```
$ aws sqs list-queues  # tried with --region us-east-2                 

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://us-east-2.queue.amazonaws.com/"
```

My configurations look correct:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ******
aws_secret_access_key = *****
aws_default_region = us-east-2

$ cat ~/.aws/config     
[default]
region = us-east-2
```

The strange thing is that if I try connecting to another service such as S3 I don't get any error:

```
$ aws s3 ls             
2019-06-27 17:02:33 codepipe-us-east-2-1037621333
```

**UPDATE**

On a different Network, `aws sqs list-queues` works correctly. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What aws cli version are you using?

Comment: `awscli==1.16.258`

Comment: it should work, happen when no internet connection. the config seems valid

Comment: I have connection. I tried S3 and that worked. It’s only for sqs

Comment: S3 endpoint is a gateway, SQS is an interface. Their concepts are slightly different. Not clear what is your setup. Have you tried to create a dedicated endpoint under VPC?